# Customize the Decimal Pad in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iphone ap that allows users to input decimal values into text fields. I need users to be able to set these values as positive or negative.

I've seen several posts inquiring about adding a decimal to the number pad, but this was addressed with the decimal pad. I need to also include a "-/+" button.

Is this the best approach? Can somebody point me to a good resource on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [inputAccessoryView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView) to add custom controls to the keyboard, this is popular in many apps including google chrome.

```
yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = //yourView having custom buttons for decimal and plus etc
```